# How to detect serial port plug-and-play events in Qt?

Tags: qt, serial-port

I'm working on serial port communication using the Qt framework, and I need to receive notifications when a serial port is plugged or unplugged. I have gone through the Qt documentation but couldn't find specific information on how to detect serial port plug-and-play events.

I'm wondering how I can achieve functionality similar to the plug-and-play events issued by the operating system when a USB device is inserted. Are there any Qt signals or methods available to help me accomplish this within my Qt application?

I am currently using QTimer to poll and detect if there are new serial ports inserted or existing ones unplugged. The code is as follows:

```cpp
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]() {
        QList<QSerialPortInfo> serialPorts = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
        ui->serialPortComboBox->clear();
        for (const QSerialPortInfo &info : serialPorts) {
            ui->serialPortComboBox->addItem(info.portName());
        });
timer->start(1000);
```

However, I would like to achieve the detection of serial port plug-and-play events in an event-driven manner. How can I accomplish this?